# Speed issues in several hibernate queries

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm building a graph algorithm using vertex and edges objects, persisted with hibernate. This code needs to do intense work when checking edges to discover whether they status (and another code to "recognize" vertex should do something like it).

Classes:

```
 Vertex(long id, String name);
 Edge(long id, Vertex v, Vertex w, boolean visited);
 VertexDAO(Vertex vertex);//persistence class for vertex implemented with hibernate
 EdgeDAO(Edge edge);//persistence class for vertex implemented with hibernate
```

I have two options to set/update visited edges in my graph:

1. Querying DAO objects to retrieve (un)visited edges (through hibernate) and set them as necessary;
   Problem: I don't know the cost of these operations, and if it would be efficient when the graph goes big; and it doesn't seems to me the best solution;
2. Testing my own set of edges to retrieve all those which were(n't) been visited.
   Problem: probably my searh algorithm is worst than hibernate one,and it may represent a reduction in performance compared to the previous alternative, if hibernate manage the objects efficiently in memory and doesn't need to persist or overhead them so much.

Have you any experience or tip in this case? Thanks for helping.

Comment: I hear graph and performance and think: you should use a graph db. Neo4j for instance.

Comment: @kabram, goot tip, but I've the system implemented, and I'm just making improvements. Now I have to choose one approach from these above.

Comment: Then introduce a second-level cache and keep the whole thing in memory. Keep the tree-relationship table minimal (keys only). Or just load everything and keep it in memory.